# Error when uploading MLP regressor locally in Jupyter from a pickle file created in Azure

Tags: python, azure, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, pickle

I have made an MLP model using sklearn which I saved as a .pkl file. I can upload it in Azure Jupyter notebooks, but not locally. The following error message appears when loading the model:

```
No module named 'sklearn.neural_network._multilayer_perceptron'
```

I installed the sklearn version '0.22.2.post1' for jupyter notebooks (since this is the version the MLP model was created in Azure). Does anyone know what the problem with upload the MLP model could be and how to solve it?

When running the line: 'sklearn.**version**', it said to be the version '0.22.2.post1' both when using it in Jupyter Notebooks in Azure and locally in Jupyter Notebooks.

As for relevant code parts, the MLP models are stored in a dictionary (called models) and then saved as a pickle file (name_of_dicktionary_the_models_are_saved_in.pkl):

`ml_results_file = open("folder/name_of_dicktionary_the_models_are_saved_in.pkl", "wb") pickle.dump(models, ml_results_file)  ml_results_file.close()`

The way the pickle files are opened is:

`ml_results_file = open("folder/name_of_dicktionary_the_models_are_saved_in.pkl", "rb") models = pickle.load(ml_results_file) ml_results_file.close()`

Comment: Did you try importing that module - or other parts of sklearn -  "by hand" / just as one import statement in your notebook , as to make sure it is actually available.
Posting relevant code parts here could also be helpful in answering the question.

Comment: Thanks for answering @mfit :)  I have tried importing the sklearn library again, just to be sure it is the right version. As well, I have imported the scikit-learn version 0.22.2.post1, since this is the version the model created in Azure used. Neither solved the problem. I have now updated the post above with some code parts, hope can clarify the problem better.